# How did I get a value larger than 8 bits in size from an 8-bit integer?

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-behavior

I tracked down an extremely nasty bug hiding behind this little gem. I am aware that per the C++ spec, signed overflows are undefined behavior, but only when the overflow occurs when the value is extended to bit-width `sizeof(int)`. As I understand it, incrementing a `char` shouldn't ever be undefined behavior as long as `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)`. But that doesn't explain how `c` is getting an *impossible* value. As an 8-bit integer, how can `c` hold values greater than its bit-width?

### Code

```cpp
// Compiled with gcc-4.7.2
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
   int8_t c = 0;
   printf("SCHAR_MIN: %i\n", SCHAR_MIN);
   printf("SCHAR_MAX: %i\n", SCHAR_MAX);

   for (int32_t i = 0; i <= 300; i++)
      printf("c: %i\n", c--);

   printf("c: %i\n", c);

   return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
SCHAR_MIN: -128
SCHAR_MAX: 127
c: 0
c: -1
c: -2
c: -3
...
c: -127
c: -128  // <= The next value should still be an 8-bit value.
c: -129  // <= What? That's more than 8 bits!
c: -130  // <= Uh...
c: -131
...
c: -297
c: -298  // <= Getting ridiculous now.
c: -299
c: -300
c: -45   // <= ..........
```

### [Check it out on ideone.](http://ideone.com/93syPL)

Comment: "I am aware that per the C++ spec, signed overflows are undefined." -- Right. To be precise, not just the *value* is undefined, the *behaviour* is. Appearing to get physically impossible results is a valid consequence.

Comment: @hvd I'm sure someone has an explanation for how common C++ implementations cause this behavior. Perhaps it has to do with alignment or how `printf()` does conversion?

Comment: Others have addressed the main issue. My comment is more general and relates to diagnostic approaches. I believe part of why you found this  such a puzzle is the unerlying belief it was ijpossible. Obviously, it is not impossible, so accept that and look again

Comment: @TimX - I observed the behavior and obviously drew the conclusion it was not impossible in that sense. My use of the word referred to an 8-bit integer holding a 9-bit value, which is an impossibility by definition. The fact that this happened suggests that it is not being treated as an 8-bit value. As others have addressed, this is due to a compiler bug. The only *seeming* impossibility here is a 9-bit value in an 8-bit space, and this apparent impossibility is explained by the space actually being "larger" than reported.

Comment: I have just tested it on my mechine, and the result is just what it should be. c: -120 c: -121 c: -122 c: -123 c: -124 c: -125 c: -126 c: -127 c: -128 c: 127 c: 126 c: 125 c: 124 c: 123 c: 122 c: 121 c: 120 c: 119 c: 118 c: 117 And my environment is:
Ubuntu-12.10 gcc-4.7.2

Comment: I believe the issue is with the '%i' format used in your printf line. %i displays the argument given as an int value. I don't know if there's a format to display the value as an 8-bit value. Possibly %hi will do it. Here's the format string syntax: % [flags] [field_width] [.precision] [length_modifier] conversion_character

Comment: what happens if you change to: --c; printf("c: %i\n", c);

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[This is a compiler bug.](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35634)

Although getting impossible results for undefined behaviour is a valid consequence, there is actually no undefined behaviour in your code. What's happening is that the compiler *thinks* the behaviour is undefined, and optimises accordingly.

If `c` is defined as `int8_t`, and `int8_t` promotes to `int`, then `c--` is supposed to perform the subtraction `c - 1` in `int` arithmetic and convert the result back to `int8_t`. The subtraction in `int` does not overflow, and converting out-of-range integral values to another integral type is valid. If the destination type is signed, the result is implementation-defined, but it must be a valid value for the destination type. (And if the destination type is unsigned, the result is well-defined, but that does not apply here.)

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as a "bug". Since signed overflow causes undefined behaviour, the compiler is perfectly entitled to assume it won't happen, and optimise the loop to keep intermediate values of `c` in a wider type. Presumably, that's what's happening here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: The only overflow here is on the (implicit) conversion. Overflow on signed conversion does not have undefined behavior; it merely yields an implementation-defined result (or raises an implementation-defined signal, but that doesn't seem to be happening here). The difference in definedness between arithmetic operations and conversions is odd, but that's the way the language standard defines it.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's something that differs between C and C++: C allows for an implementation-defined signal, C++ does not. C++ just says "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined."

Comment: As it happens, I can't reproduce the odd behaviour on g++ 4.8.0.

Comment: @DanielLandau See comment 38 in that bug: "Fixed for 4.8.0." :)

Comment: A quick fix would be to pass `-fwrapv` or `-fno-strict-overflow`, since `-O2` enables `-fstrict-overflow` which is causing the problem.

Comment: What benefits are offered by making the behavior implementation-defined rather than undefined, so as to justify the cost of producing extra code to enforce a particular result?  Or could a compiler document the behavior by specifying that conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed type will yield a value whose lower bits are correct and whose higher bits will be whatever the compiler feels like?

Comment: @supercat I suspect that the answer to that is mainly historical, that no compiler when C was being written gave unpredictable results, that the goal was to render existing code which used such conversions valid (but implementation-dependent), and that no implementations were imaginable where the conversion would cause any problem.

Comment: @hvd: There are many platforms, including historical ones, where allowing a compiler to have (signed char)129 arbitrarily evaluate to -127 or 129, could improve the usefulness or register optimizations.  Code targeting a particular implementation may benefit from knowing what that implementation will do, and code targeting any implementation may benefit from knowing that its behavior must be chosen from a certain set of alternatives (e.g. that the result of (signed char)129 must be a number of the form (N*256)+129), but from what I understand, a compiler could legitimately...

Comment: ...decide that (signed char)129 should yield 42 provided its documentation says so.  Thus, any code which ever converts out-of-ranged values to signed integer types would be non-portable; code written for particular implementations which specify consistent behavior could benefit from that specification, but I'm not sure what value there is in merely requiring that a behavior be consistent without saying what it should be.  If I were writing the standard, an explicit cast would have fully specified behavior; a type coercion would yield something of the earlier-indicated form.

Comment: @supercat You're right, an implementation can make (signed char)129 evaluate to 42. Back when the first C standard was being written, both other representations than two's complement and other byte sizes than 8 were more common than now. There were significant systems back then where (N*256)+129 would not be a sensible choice. Back when the first C standard was being written, it was also not certain at all whether compilers and users would adopt the standard, and in that sense, choosing to make existing code implementation-defined rather than undefined may have benefited in that area.

Comment: @hvd: If your argument is that the spec shouldn't specify a particular relationship between the original value and what results, I can go along with that.  I'm curious, though, whether an implementation whose documentation *explicitly stated* that out-of-range conversions could yield inconsistent results could be deemed conforming, and also what advantage there would be in knowing that out-of-range conversions will be handled in some consistent vendor-specific way, versus merely knowing that the result would be an arbitrary not-necessarily-predictable value.

Comment: @supercat I do not know whether such an implementation could be valid, good question. I suspect not, but I could easily be mistaken. And a benefit of the implementation-defined result that I forgot is exactly this question, and GCC's response: it was intended to be consistent, it accidentally wasn't, and GCC made it consistent again instead of saying the code is buggy :)

Comment: @hvd: Since the standard seems to have a fair bit of room for trap representations and resulting Undefined Behavior, could a compiler specify that, for purposes of standards-compliance, storing an out-of-range value into a signed short that was never aliased would cause it to hold a trap representation, with no guarantees as to what might happen if it's read?

Comment: @supercat C++ doesn't have the concept of trap representations, and in C (C99, anyway, I don't know about C11), the result of a cast is not an object, so it has no representation, just a value. A trap representation is a representation that does not map to a value, a cast produces a value, so a cast cannot produce a trap representation. The option to raise an implementation-defined signal (also not allowed in C++) might provide some options, though: as far as I recall, if you don't have a signal handler, the behaviour is undefined. If you do have a handler, and it returns, the same.

Comment: @supercat However, that would still allow a program to handle the signal by exiting cleanly, so I don't know how well an implementation could make use of this option.

Comment: @hvd: Implementations are required to either hold an implementation-defined value or raise a signal, but I didn't see anything that said the value couldn't be a trap representation.  A trap representation would have two differences from a signal: (1) Reading the value via any means other than aliasing to unsigned char would be *100% undefined behavior*; (2) If the value is never read, there would be no undefined behavior but the value wouldn't matter.  The kinds of optimization where returning an indeterminate value would be helpful are inapplicable for aliased variables, and...

Comment: ...would be legitimate if the value is never read [I think passing a trap representation as a parameter which ends up being ignored is legit, so the compiler may not be able to determine whether the value will be read].  Such usage of "trap representation" would certainly not what the authors of the spec intended, but would seem to be a valid way of interpreting the spec to allow a specification to say a value was indeterminate.

Comment: @supercat A trap representation isn't a value, so if it has to be a value, it cannot be a trap representation. "implementation-defined value" is defined as "unspecified value where each implementation documents how the choice is made" (3.17.1). "unspecified value" is defined as "valid value of the relevant type where this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance" (3.17.3), with an explicit note "An unspecified value cannot be a trap representation." (Between them is "indeterminate value", which confusingly is *not* necessarily a value.)

Comment: @supercat "Trap representation", btw, is defined as "Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. [...] Such a representation is called a *trap representation*." (6.2.6.1), which also supports the idea that a value can never be a trap representation.

Comment: @hvd: Hmm... that would seem to pretty well imply that a compiler would have to spend instructions coercing the result into the proper type.  I wonder if there are any practical programs which would be guaranteed to work correctly under the standard which would not be guaranteed to work correctly if given e.g. `short foo(int x) {return x+1;} int bar(int x) {return foo(x);}` the standard allowed `bar(32767)` to return 32768?  [note that whether legitimate or not, many compilers occasionally exhibit such behavior]

Comment: @supercat I think I've seen `int x;` `short hi = x >> 16, lo = x;` and similar without explicit masking, even with signed types.

Comment: @hvd: I've seen such code targeting compilers *whose documentation says what they will do*, but such code is not guaranteed to work correctly by the standard.  Is there any practical code which would work if e.g. a compiler decided to evaluate any out-of-bounds cast as yielding the value 42 [clearly allowed by the standard, if documented], which would fail if any attempt to do anything with the result other than pass it around was Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @supercat I think I've seen `(short) i == i` to test whether `i` fits in a `short`. It could easily be rewritten to avoid an out-of-range conversion, but it's currently valid and possibly useful (C++ doest't yet allow an implemwntation-defined signal to be raised, IIRC)

Comment: @hvd: That seems practical, if signals are not an allowed response to an out-of-range value.  Still, the rules for what things are and are not allowed to seem a bit of a muddle.  It would be nice if things could shift toward a language where existing C code could would using non-preferred constructs, but be migrated toward using ones that could allow faster or better-defined semantics, e.g. by adding new unsigned types which would explicitly represent numbers and abstract algebraic rings, rather than trying to be a hybrid of both.

Comment: @hvd: If `int` is 16 bits, an `unsigned int` will mostly behave like an element the algebraic ring Z65536, except that adding anything to an element of a ring should, when allowed, always yield an element of the same ring (so adding a 32-bit `signed long` to a Z65536 should yield a 65536 rather than a `signed long`, and adding an element of any other ring without a typecast should be forbidden).  The idea of replacing things like `long` with `int64_t` is nice, but they really don't map to C types.  Given `uint_fast8_t x=0; int32_t y=-1; int64_t z = x+y;`, what should `z` be?

Comment: @supercat Heh, yes, mixing different specific-width types doesn't really work well. I don't think that's the point of those types, and agreed that it would be nice to have some compile-time diagnostic for that. I do think we're steering a bit too far off of the topic, though. This isn't about either C or C++ anymore, it's more about what a different (possibly better) C or C++-like language would do :)

Answer (score 15):

A compiler can have bugs which are other than nonconformances to the standard, because there are other requirements. A compiler should be compatible with other versions of itself. It may also be expected to be compatible in some ways with other compilers, and also to conform to some beliefs about behavior that are held by the majority of its user base.

In this case, it appears to be a conformance bug. The expression `c--` should manipulate `c` in a way similar to `c = c - 1`.  Here, the value of `c` on the right is promoted to type `int`, and then the subtraction takes place. Since `c` is in the range of `int8_t`, this subtraction will not overflow, but it may produce a value which is out of the range of `int8_t`.  When this value is assigned, a conversion takes place back to the type `int8_t` so the result fits back into `c`. In the out-of-range case, the conversion has an implementation-defined value.  **But a value out of the range of `int8_t` is not a valid implementation-defined value.  An implementation cannot "define" that an 8 bit type suddenly holds 9 or more bits.**  For the value to be implementation-defined means that something in the range of `int8_t` is produced, and the program continues. **The C standard thereby allows for behaviors such as saturation arithmetic (common on DSP's) or wrap-around (mainstream architectures).**

The compiler is using a wider underlying machine type when manipulating values of small integer types like `int8_t` or `char`. When arithmetic is performed, results which are out of range of the small integer type can be captured reliably in this wider type. To preserve the externally visible behavior that the variable is an 8 bit type, the wider result has to be truncated into the 8 bit range. Explicit code is required to do that since the machine storage locations (registers) are wider than 8 bits and happy with the larger values. Here, the compiler **neglected to normalize** the value and simply passed it to `printf` as is. The conversion specifier `%i` in `printf` has no idea that the argument originally came from `int8_t` calculations; it is just working with an `int` argument.

Comment: This is a lucid explanation.

Comment: The compiler produces good code with the optimizer turned off. Therefore, explanations using "rules" and "definitions" aren't applicable. It's a bug in the optimizer.

Answer (score 14):

**I can't fit this in a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer.**

For some very odd reason, the `--` operator happens to be the culprit.

I tested the code posted on Ideone and replaced `c--` with `c = c - 1` and the values remained within the range [-128 ... 127]:

```
c: -123
c: -124
c: -125
c: -126
c: -127
c: -128 // about to overflow
c: 127  // woop
c: 126
c: 125
c: 124
c: 123
c: 122
```

Freaky ey? I don't know much about what the compiler does to expressions like `i++` or `i--`. It's likely promoting the return value to an `int` and passing it. That's the only logical conclusion I can come up with because you ARE in fact getting values that cannot fit into 8-bits.

Comment: Because of the integral promotions, `c = c - 1` means `c = (int8_t) ((int)c - 1`. Converting an out-of-range `int` to `int8_t` has defined behaviour but an implementation-defined result. Actually, isn't  `c--` is supposed to perform those same conversions too?

Answer (score 12):

I guess that the underlying hardware is still using a 32-bit register to hold that int8_t. Since the specification does not impose a behaviour for overflow, the implementation does not check for overflow and allows larger values to be stored as well.

---

If you mark the local variable as `volatile` you are forcing to use memory for it and consequently obtain the expected values within the range.

Comment: Oh wow. I forgot that the compiled assembly will store local variables in registers if it can. This seems like the most likely answer along with `printf` not caring about the `sizeof` the format values.

Comment: @roliu Run g++ -O2 -S code.cpp , and you'll see the assembly. Moreover, printf() is a variable argument function, so arguments whose rank are less than an int will be promoted to an int.

Comment: @nos I would like to. I haven't been able to install a UEFI boot loader (rEFInd in particular) to get archlinux running on my machine, so I haven't actually coded with GNU tools in a long time. I'll get to it... eventually. For now it's just C# in VS and trying to remember C/learn some C++ :)

Comment: @rollu Run it in a virtual machine, e.g VirtualBox

Comment: @nos Don't want to derail topic, but yeah, I could. I could also just install linux with a BIOS bootloader. I'm just stubborn and if I can't get it working with a UEFI bootloader then I probably won't get it working at all :P.

Answer (score 11):

The assembler code reveals the problem:

```
:loop
mov esi, ebx
xor eax, eax
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2   ;"c: %i\n"
sub ebx, 1
call    printf
cmp ebx, -301
jne loop

mov esi, -45
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2   ;"c: %i\n"
xor eax, eax
call    printf
```

EBX should be anded with FF post decrement, or only BL should be used with the remainder of EBX clear. Curious that it uses sub instead of dec. The -45 is flat-out mysterious. It's the bitwise inversion of 300 & 255 = 44. -45 = ~44. There's a connection somewhere.

It goes through a lot more work using c = c - 1:

```
mov eax, ebx
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2   ;"c: %i\n"
add ebx, 1
not eax
movsx   ebp, al                 ;uses only the lower 8 bits
xor eax, eax
mov esi, ebp
```

It then uses only the low portion of RAX, so it's restricted to -128 thru 127. Compiler options "-g -O2".

With no optimization, it produces correct code:

```
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
sub eax, 1
mov BYTE PTR [rbp-1], al
movsx   edx, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
mov eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2   ;"c: %i\n"
mov esi, edx
```

So it's a bug in the optimizer.

Answer (score 4):

Use `%hhd` instead of `%i`! Should solve your problem.

What you see there is the result of compiler optimizations combined with you telling printf to print a 32bit number and then pushing a (supposedly 8bit) number onto the stack, which is really pointer sized, because this is how the push opcode in x86 works.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the original behavior on my system using `g++ -O3`. Changing `%i` to `%hhd` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is doing by optimization of the code:

```
for (int32_t i = 0; i <= 300; i++)
      printf("c: %i\n", c--);
```

The compilator use the `int32_t i` variable both for `i` and `c`. Turn off optimization or make direct cast           `printf("c: %i\n", (int8_t)c--);`

Comment: Then turn off optimization. or do something like this: `(int8_t)(c & 0x0000ffff)--`

Answer (score 1):

`c` is itself defined as `int8_t`, but when operating `++` or `--` over `int8_t` it is implicitly converted first to `int` and the **result of operation** instead **the internal value of c** is printed with printf which happens to be `int`.

See the **actual value** of `c` after entire loop, especially **after last decrement**

```
-301 + 256 = -45 (since it revolved entire 8 bit range once)
```

its the correct value which resembles the behaviour `-128 + 1 = 127`

`c` starts to use `int` size memory but printed as `int8_t` when printed as itself using only `8 bits`. Utilizes all `32 bits` when used as `int`

[Compiler Bug]

Answer (score 0):

I think it happened because your loop will go until the int i will become 300 and c become -300.
And the last value is because

```
printf("c: %i\n", c);
```

Comment: 'c' is an 8 bit value, therefore it's impossible for it to ever hold a number as large as -300.